# posting select option to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, tags, html-select

this is my code:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO jokes (headline, text, type) VALUES ('{$_POST['headline']}','{$_POST['text']}', '{$_POST['type']}')") or die(mysql_error());
```

I want to post a select option, as

```
<select name="type">  
<option value="regular">regular joke</option>  
<option value="other">other</option>
</select>
```

That is my theory, but it doesnt work (it doesnt appear in the db, i have an enum field with regular and other). Any help?

Edit: Nevermind, i changed the enum to varchar and now it works :)

Comment: "it doesnt work" Can you be more specific? What error message or undesirable behaviour do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Alter your database something like this and then execute your insert query i hope its work for you

```
alter table `database_name`.`jokes` change `type` `type` enum('regular','other') NULL ;
```

Comment: I wonder if the word `type` is not reserved and will cause headaches later on to use that as a table name.

Answer (score 0):

This line will definitely throw an error since you have single quotes (for the POST array names) nested inside more single quotes.
Either escape those or write it like:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO jokes (headline, text, type) VALUES ('" . $_POST['headline']. "','" . $_POST['text'] . "', '" . $_POST['type'] . "')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Also to avoid lots of headaches and unknown errors you should never use reserved words as variables like:

```
text
type
```

When I just started out with PHP a long time ago I had hours if not days of headaches because I had a mySql field named: USER (a reserved mySql word, but this can be fixed by encasing it in ` backward quote signs)